# Cómo puedo mostrar el valor de una variable pública de un formulario en un label de otro formulario en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, variables

a ver si me explico, tengo un sistema creado en C# dónde tengo un formulario LogIn para el acceso de usuarios, en éste Login capturo en dos variables string el NOMBRE y APELLIDO del usuario para posteriormente mostrarlas en el FrmPrincipal, seguido de ésto si el ususario y la contraseña coinciden el login da acceso al FrmPrincipal, este FrmPrincipal es un MDI, cuándo quiero abrir el formulario FrmVentaRapida dentro de FrmPrincipal, quiero que la variable NOMBRE y APELLIDO se muestren en un LABEL que tengo dentro de éste Form (FrmVentaRapida), he tratado de asignar la variable haciendo referencia al FrmPrincipal pero no me muestra ningún valor, como si el string estuviera vacío, sin embargo en el LABEL que tengo en FrmPrincipal si muestra el NOMBRE y APELLIDO, es por eso que sé que la variable si los captura, tengo poca experiencia con C#, espero pudieran ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: Recuerda marcas la respuesta que te sirvió como correcta para que ayude a otros usuarios.

Comment: Sería bueno que agregues el código que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

espero poder explicarme, 
TUS FORMS SON:

1. FrmLogin
2. FrmPrincipal
3. FrmVentaRapida

En FrmVentaRapida, busca tu LABEL en el FrmVentaRapida.Designer.cs y agrega public en lugar de private

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Label lNombre;
public System.Windows.Forms.Label lApellido;
```

---

Si esta parte no funciona, crea un par de variables publicas en la clase de frmVentaRapida, dichas variables se las pasas en tu evento donde mandas llamar a dicha Forma

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string nombre = "";
        public string apellido = "";

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lNombre.Text = "";
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lNombre.Text = nombre;
            lApellido.Text = apellido;

        }
    }
```

Y esta acción cuando mandes llamar tu evento de la frmVentaRapida

```
private void btnF2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 f2 = new Form2();
  f2.nombre = "test";
  f2.apellido = "abc";
}
```

Espero haberme explicado, ya que no has puesto tu código,
Saludos..

Comment: Exponer los controles de un formulario es una mala práctica, además de que no es recomendable modificar el código generado por el diseñador. Es mejor encapsular las propiedades de los controles en propiedades del form. Creo que sería bueno que elimine la primera parte de su respuesta.

Comment: @Xam, buen día, muy bien lo tendré en mente, seria bueno que dejaras un link sobre esa mala practica. Saludos!!!

Answer (score 0):

Formulario que envía el dato:

```
string SelectedCoupon = "12345"
Form1 _Form1 = new Form1(this.SelectedCoupon);

_Form1 .Owner = this;
_Form1 .ShowDialog();
```

Formualrio que recibe el dato:

```
string datorecibido;


    public Form1 ()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public Form1 (string variablerecibida) : this()
            {
                datorecibido = variablerecibida;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

algo tarde al post pero  les comento como lo resolví por si en un futuro a alguien la sirve:

Creé una nueva clase pública, con propiedades estáticas privadas a las cuales quiero acceder (private static string _IdUsuario, por ejemplo),  las encapsulé y accedo a ellas desde el formulario que deseo, ya que la clase es pública. Algo asi comentaba @Xam, solo que en mi personal opinión dió una explicación MUY general y por encima de la solución y no quedó muy claro, de todos modos muchas gracias, me han ayudado bastante. Saludos.